# Override method using superclass/trait implementation

Tags: scala

Suppose I have next traits:

```
trait A {
  val a: String = "a"
}

trait B {
  def a: String = "b"
}
```

And I want to mix both of these traits into some class `C`

`class C extends B with A`

Compiler doesn't allow me to create such class because I have to override method `a`

I want to override it using for example only `A`'s implementaion. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

```
scala> class C extends B with A {
     | override val a = super.a
     | }
<console>:10: error: super may be not be used on value a
       override val a = super.a
                              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't possibly know which one you intend to use, therefore you must specify it like:

```
class C extends B with A {
    override def a = super[A].a
}
```

This approach allows you to choose the parent directly, regardless the trait order.

However, the traits define `a` differently (`val` and `def`) thus you must choose only one. You should use either `def` or `val` in both traits (not mix them).

Comment: this will not compile

Comment: Have you unified `def` and `val` in traits? What scala version do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Provided you make `a` a `def` in the `A` trait, you can do

```
class C extends B with A {
  override val a = super.a
}

val c = new C
c.a // "a"
```

This will work because `A` is extended after `B`, so `super` will be its implementation.

Comment: this will not compile

Comment: @maks, read my answer carefully. You need to make `a` a `def` in `A`.

Comment: in my question I provided just an example. In reality `A` and `B` is a library code

Comment: you should specify it in the question then. This makes a big difference and you cannot refer to a `super` value from a subclass.